# Data refresh on AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of customers on my DB who all joined at different years.  I have configured my api to suit this and works fine.  And my code with Angularjs works in pulling in the right data, only problem because it is the same route eg /customers/:id it doesnt refresh the data, it does refresh it if i manually refresh the browser.  Any help will be great.

HTML links

```
<table>    
<tr><td><a href="#customers/2014">2014</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#customers/2013">2013</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#customers/2012">2012</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

App.js (sample of where its called)

```
.when("/Archive/:param/", {
        templateUrl: "Customers/Customers.html",
        controller:"CustomersController"
    })
```

CustomersController

```
 (function () {

var CustomersController = function ($scope, customerService, $log, $routeParams, $location, $sce) {

    var param = $routeParams.param;
    var customer = function (data) {
    $scope.Customer= data;
    };

    var errorDetails = function (serviceResp) {
        $scope.Error = "Something went wrong ??";
    };

    var refresh = function () {
        customerService.customer(param)
        .then(customer, errorDetails);
    };

    refresh();


};

app.controller("CustomersController", ["$scope", "customerService", "$log", "$routeParams", "$location", "$sce", CustomersController]);
}());
```

CustomerService.js

```
    (function () {
    var customerService = function ($http, $q, $log, $scope) {
        var cachedCustomer;

        var customer = function (param) {
            var params = param;
            console.log("this is the "+params);

            if (cachedCustomer)
                return $q.when(cachedCustomer);

            return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/customers/year/" + params)
                        .then(function (serviceResp) {

                            $log.info(cachedCustomer);
                            cachedCustomer = serviceResp.data;
                            $log.info(cachedCustomer);
                            return serviceResp.data;
                        });
        };

        return {
            customer: customer,

        };
    };

    var module = angular.module("CustomerModule");
    module.factory("customerService", ["$http", "$q", "$log", customerService]);
}());
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of this: `if (cachedCustomer) return $q.when(cachedCustomer);`

Comment: Hey I deleted this line of code for now and it works :)  Thank you for pointing where the issue lies :)

Answer (score 2):

In customerService.js in this line

```
                if (cachedCustomer)
                  return $q.when(cachedCustomer);
```

you are checking for a cached result, and then returning that cached result if it exists. Since you set the cache in your `.then` block, and you never remove it, the $http call is only every made once since services act as singleton objects. If you want to be able to get updated information, I recommend either adding a flag to customerService.customer() that skips the cache check. Alternatively, in customerService, instead of caching the result of the promise (the data) you can just cache the unresolved promise itself, and then clear this once you receive the data in your `.then`. This prevents multiple calls to $http being made until at least 1 resolves / gets rejected

Comment: Hey I deleted this line of code for now and it works :)  Thank you for pointing where the issue lies :)

Answer (score 0):

The browser refresh is indeed clearing the **cachedCustomer** and re-requesting the information. You should indicate that you need to clear your **cachedCustomer** when changing the *year* paramater you're passing.

You could create a caching service that stores the customer information based on the **URL** they are requested from. In other words you can create an array similar like a hashmap that stores the information as value and uses the **URL** as key. Although I wouldn't recommend this when your data is being altered (on the back-end) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$route.reload();
```

Please inject $route in your controller